# Start Raspbmc via Logitech Unifying receiver

Tags: raspbmc, power-management

I have a my `Raspbmc` connected to my TV and i control it with a `Logitech Unifying receiver` Keyboard (Logitech k400). On this Keyboard there is a Power-Button that can turn on the connected PC, but it doesn't work with my `raspberry`. I always have to plug the `raspberry` off and on to start it after i shut down `raspbmc`.

Is there any possibility to start the `raspberry pi` with a connected keyboard (like Wake-on-lan)?

Comment: you are using XBMC?

Comment: yes, raspbmc exactly.

Comment: Your keyboard comes with a dongle... this dongle is in no way a bluetooth don ogle it emulates a keyboard interface but - to my understanding - only when it is powered (when the computer it's connected to is powered). I fear your question is misleading and should be entirely rewritten to properly address the issue with the particular hardware you are using.

Comment: Actually that button is just for sleep, you can't power on and off any PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well your topic is quiet interesting for me too, but..

IMHO i dont think that it is possible to boot a device via bluetooth remotly, because the system is completly unloaded.

you tried to switch hibernate/sleep mode with your bt keyboard? i think that should be just a configuration issue.. but ok.. offtopic.

maybe you can fit your needs with a remote power socket? your boot time should be quiet good.. so there is no significant difference in wakeup or boot device.

let me know if i´m wrong..

--- edit ---

if your tv has usb. you can plug the raspberry there.. now the pi will start with the upstart of your tv. (done) if you switch your tv off - the pi will be switched off too.. before that you can quit raspbmc from gui or whatever..

Comment: If you go for this solution _make sure_ your pi is safely powered off, before turning off the tv, as an unexpected power outage might corrupt your SD card

Comment: @Jervelund you are completly right. futhermore you should make an backup image of your installed pi, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any possibility to start the raspberry pi with a connected keyboard (like Wake-on-lan)?

**No.**  The pi does not have any power modes besides "on", which is what it is while plugged in.  I believe it is capable of recieving a WOL packet if it is plugged in, but of course that won't change anything, because if it is plugged in, it is already on.

Once you've shut down the system that's running on it, the system has stopped, but the pi is technically still "on", which is why you must then unplug and replug it to reboot.